# MTPDevice.open(usbDeviceConnection) returns false

Tags: android, usb, mtp, usb-mass-storage

I want to print the all the files in the usb device.
I am trying to open the mtpDevice, but the open function returns false.

```
device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(device);

MtpDevice mtpDevice = new MtpDevice(device);

if (!mtpDevice.open(usbDeviceConnection)) { 
            return ;
} // open returns false..

MtpDeviceInfo info  = mtpDevice.getDeviceInfo(); // returns null

int[] storageIds = mtpDevice.getStorageIds(); // storageIds is null
```

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I know this is very old, but did you ever get it working? I'm having exactly the same problem.